# When is Element.getBoundingClientRect guaranteed to be updated / accurate?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reflow, getboundingclientrect

I am working on some code that uses [`Element.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) (gBCR), coupled with inline style updates, to perform calculation. *This is not for a general website* and I am not concerned or interested in if there are "better CSS ways" of doing this task.

The JavaScript is run *synchronously* and performs these steps:

1. The parent's gBCR is fetched
2. Calculations are performed and;
3. A *child element* of the parent has *inline CSS styles* (eg. size and margins) updated
4. The parent's gBCR is fetched again

*Am I guaranteed that the computed client bounds will reflect the new bounding rectangle of the parent at step 4*?

If not guaranteed by a specification, is this *"guaranteed*" by modern<sup>1</sup> browser implementations? If "mostly guaranteed", what notable exceptions are there?

Elements are *not* being added to or removed from the DOM and the elements being modified are direct children of the parent node; if such restrictions / information is relevant.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Modern": UIWebView (iOS 6+), WebView (Android 2+), and the usual Chrome/WebKit, FF, IE9+ suspects - *including* mobile versions.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I've done A LOT of work with gBCR, and I'm almost 100% positive it works, since many SO questions about how to "manually refresh" the page's styles include calling gBCR. I'll get some links

Comment: @Markasoftware That sounds encouraging! I've had no issue with desktop browsers (IE10+ etc.), but my experience is limited and I do not have a way of testing on mobile devices or OS X.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that it is not updated in real-time?

Comment: I believe (but am not sure) that gBCR forces a relayout, which is why some recommend against overusing it. For other possibly useful information, see http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2064869&start=0,

Comment: @user2864740 well, IE counts for some mobile devices (namely some tablets and winphone, so that's a lot of users :). If you're really interested in testing for android, you can use Bluestacks or (my favorite) Andy for android emulation on windows

Comment: @Markasoftware Thanks for the suggestions - and I updated the question to include IE a bit more ;-)

Comment: @torazaburo I do not have a counter-example at the moment. The problem is when it "Works Here (TM)", but fails to work on a different device/browser. Unless the behavior is guaranteed (or there is a high degree of confidence that it is "guaranteed"), then I am walking on ice, of varying thickness - it's not fun to trust an entire approach to something that falls apart later. I'm not sure if *not* doing a DOM-tree manipulation affects the result/expectations.

Comment: I do not have any authoritative resources to back me up, so someone who knows the engine should really answer, but I think you are on quite safe ground, based on everything I have seen, in assuming that gBCR always returns updated/accurate results.

Comment: chrome 44 stable gBCR giving wrong data for a large document.  struggling to create a small test case

Answer (score 1):

I'm just stuck at gBCR unreliability on ios8.4.1/Safari8.0.

Prepare a large div on top of body (gBCR is 0) and scroll to bottom (gBCR is negative). Resize the div into 1x1 then `window.scrollY` automatically goes 0. gBCR should also be 0 but still stay negative value. With `setTimeout`, 200ms later, you can confirm the right value 0.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, still the problem puzzled me and in my searches I had tumbled on this question. It might help others.

The best guarantee that I could find to make `getBoundingClientRect()` work reliably is to force a refresh at the top of the window, calculate the positions, and then go back wherever the user was.

Code would look something like:

```
  scroll_pos = document.documentElement.scrollTop // save current position
  window.scrollTo(0, 0); // go up

  v_align = parseInt(el.getBoundingClientRect().top) // example of gBCR for vert.alignment
  //... whatever other code you might need
  window.scrollTo(0, scroll_pos); // get back to the starting position
```

Usually the operation is lightning fast, so the user should not notice it.